# How make pages in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, paging

I would like to make pages for UserControl but I don't know how I can do this.

How can I implement this as in the picture in WinForms?

I would like to display as many cards on the page as indicated in the filter, but I don't know how to transfer the remaining cards to the next page:

[image]

My code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    flowLayout.Controls.Clear();
    MySqlConnection sqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    sqlConnection.Open();

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);

    try
    {
        using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            if (dt != null)
            {
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    ShopItem[] listItems = new ShopItem[dt.Rows.Count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            listItems[i] = new ShopItem();
                            listItems[i].id = Convert.ToInt32(row["id_order"]);
                            listItems[i].brand = row["brand"].ToString();
                            listItems[i].capacity = row["capacity"].ToString();
                            listItems[i].engine = row["engine"].ToString();
                            listItems[i].lifting_height = row["lifting_height"].ToString();
                            listItems[i].mass = row["mass"].ToString();
                            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])row["image"]);
                            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(ms);
                            listItems[i]._image = bitmap;
                            listItems[i].price = row["price"].ToString();

                            //if select first value display one item
                            if (comboBoxFilter.SelectedIndex == 0)
                            {
                                if(flowLayout.Controls.Count < Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxFilter.SelectedItem))
                                {
                                    flowLayout.Controls.Add(listItems[i]);
                                }
                            }

                            //if select second value display four item
                            if (comboBoxFilter.SelectedIndex == 1)
                            {
                                if (flowLayout.Controls.Count < Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxFilter.SelectedItem))
                                {
                                    flowLayout.Controls.Add(listItems[i]);
                                }
                            }

                            //if select third value display nine item
                            if (comboBoxFilter.SelectedIndex == 2)
                            {
                                if (flowLayout.Controls.Count < Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxFilter.SelectedItem))
                                {
                                    flowLayout.Controls.Add(listItems[i]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Pages"? In addition the last three (3) `if` statements look odd in a sense that they all do the same thing ... ? ...

Comment: Pages like in photo, I'm making a store and I want there to be 9 items in 1 FlowLayout.Controls page.

Comment: @JohnG by "pages" the pages of a paging is meant here.

Answer (score 0):

You assuming that you have a `pageSize` and a `page` value you can get the corresponding chunk from `Rows` as follows:

```
for (int myIndex = page * pageSize; myIndex < (page + 1) * pageSize; myIndex++) {
    //Do some stuff with dt.Rows[i]
}
```

However, it would be better to not even get all the rows from the database, you could modify your `query` to `limit` your results, which you can do in any RDBMS, but the syntax varied. If you would not even get all the rows from the database, then you can loop with `row` as you originally did, because the paging was already done by the query. However, if you do really want to apply the paging logic on your application server, as your question's tags suggest, then you can do the looping as suggested above.

In general, it is much better to limit the results on the RDBMS's side, so you do not fill the memory upon each request with n * page rows while you only need n x less rows. So, if you do not have a very good reason to load all the rows, then do the limitation in the query. This is especially helpful if you have big data.

Comment: I have a product description, I want to place up to 9 such product cards, then make a second page with it. What you offer is a little not suitable, I do not understand how I can make a second page with the product if it is more than 9

Comment: @Jizik51 you shouldn't preload all the data. Instead, you should display the first 9 items on the first page, the second 9 items on the second page and so on. Therefore, when you initialize your form, you should load the first 9 items only and display them. And then, when the second page is being clicked, load the second 9 items and display them, because the way you want to do it would fill the memory of your device with unnecessary data, which is a waste of resources.

Comment: So, you need a click handler for your paging buttons (prev, 1, 2, 3, ... next) that will know which page you intend to load and that will be `page`. `pageSize` is 9. So, you should aim to modify your query so that it will limit the size of the result to 9 and use `page` and `pageSize` to determine which element your result should start at.

Comment: i don't know how make page That's the question

Comment: @Jizik51 the alternative that you propose is an antipattern, it is called "extraneous fetching antipattern", see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/extraneous-fetching/

Comment: @Jizik51 you have given your application code which does the logic. You should start by limiting your results to the paging size. When that's done and you see 9 elements on your UI instead of everything, then you have fulfilled the first step successfully

Comment: @Jizik51 then, you need to create a button click event for your paging buttons, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @Jizik51 when you have your buttons on the ui and their event handlers are successfully created and are triggered (first with some dummy logic, we are only interested on the events being triggered at this point), then you have successfully completed the second step.

Comment: @Jizik51 your buttons on the UI should be aware of what page they should point to. An  example implementation can be seen at https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/custom-paging-with-gridview-control-in-Asp-Net-4-5/

Comment: @Jizik51 once the buttons have an event handler which is successfully triggered on click and you have the backend logic described in step one, you have completed step 3. Now, step 4 is to trigger the paging logic with the correct `page` in your click handler and refresh your grid with the data returned. The fifth step is to refresh your page buttons on the UI. The current page number should be unclickable, prev should not be displayed when you are on the first page and next should not be displayed when you are on the last page. You need to refresh your numbers too.

Comment: @Jizik51 in short: the approach to solve a composite question is to break it down to smaller, atomic subquestions. You have a paging to be implemented, which I'm sure looks like a dragon to you, but if you break it down to small subtasks, then you will be less confused. If my answer helped you solving your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.